# How do I properly compare two different models based on their field values and output the differences?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to figure out how to produce the output between two querysets that have similar fields.  I have two different models where I keep identical fields, and at times I want to show the differences between these two models.  I have researched and successfully used sets and lists in my python code, but I can't quite figure out how to leverage them or determine if I Can.  Sets seems to strip out just the field values, and when I try to loop through my sets, it doesn't currently work because it's just the values without the keys.

Example:

```
class Team(models.Model):

    player = models.Charfield
    coach = models.Charfield

class TeamCommittee(models.Model):

    player = models.Charfield
    coach = models.Charfield
```

I want to be able to query both models at times and be able to exclude data from one model if it exists in the other.  I have spent the afternoon trying to use sets, lists, and loops in my django templates but can't quite work this out.  I have also tried various querysets using exclude....

I tried something like....

```
query1 = TeamCommittee.objects.filter(id=self.object.pk).values('coach','player') 
query2 = Team.objects.filter(id=self.object.pk).exclude(id__in=query1)
```

When I use the approach above, I get TypeError: Cannot use multi-field values as a filter value.

I am wondering if I can do this via a query or if I need to dump my querysets and go down a path of manipulating a data dictionary?  That seems extreme for what I am trying to do though.  This does seem to be a bit more complicated because I am trying to cross reference two different models.  If it was the same model this would be a lot easier but it's not an option for this particular use case.

Thanks in advance for any thoughts on the right way to approach this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare on the basis of the ID of both tables, probably you can use this:

```
teamID = list(Team.objects.all().values_list('id', flat=True))
query1 = TeamCommittee.objects.filter(id__in=teamID)

teamCommitteeID = list(TeamCommittee.objects.all().values_list('id', flat=True))
query2 = Team.objects.filter(id__in=teamCommitteeID)
```

Comment: Saksham Agarwal thank you for the suggestion.  I have tried numerous iterations of this and it doesn't work simply because I am trying to pass in 6 different values and if they are all identical I want them to be excluded.  This appears to only work for one value.  Thank you for the suggestion though.

Comment: the code I sent will work for multiple values, basically, the first line will make a list of all id's and the second line will compare all the id's that are present in the list

Comment: I ultimately solved this.  I actually used the .values() parameter.  I was able to specify the values I wanted in my queryset, and then I looped through the values via my django template.  Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: That's great. Can you share your piece of code?

Comment: I shared it above.  That was the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was super close...Instead I just did this...

```
query1 = TeamCommittee.objects.filter(id=self.object.pk).values('coach','player').distinct()
```

Then in my template I did a very simple....

```
{% for item in query1.all %}
           item
{% endfor %}
```

Then when I wanted to get the values out of the other queryset I just did the same thing with the loop.

```
query2 = Team.objects.filter(id=self.object.pk).values('coach','player').distinct()
```

Then in my template I did a very simple....

```
{% for item in query2.all %}
           item
{% endfor %}
```

Sometimes simplicity is hard.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above after additional testing only partially worked.  I ultimately abandoned that approach and instead incorporated the logic below into my template.  I did not need to create separate queries, I just needed to loop through the fields that were already available to me as part of the DetailView I was using....

```
   {% for author in author_detail.author_set.all %}
      {% for book in book_detail.book_set.all %}
         {% if author.author_name %}
            {% if book.book_name in author.book_name %}
              {% if author.book_name == book.book_name %}
                {% elif author.book_name != book.book_name %}
                    {{ author.author_name }}
                {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
         {% endif %}
       {% endfor %}
   {% endfor %}
```

Thank you to everyone who made suggestions to get me to this point.